# How do I build the "Endless Research Park and EndlessWorld" wonder?

Tags: endless-space-2

I've just unlocked the Empire Development Deed "Endless Research Park and EndlessWorld". To complete it, I must build the aforementioned wonder in one of my star systems.

How do I build the "Endless Research Park and EndlessWorld" wonder?

I'm not seeing it in the list of improvements in the Star System Management Screen, nor do I see it as an option for system development at the moment...

Weirdly enough about an hour after I posted the question, *it did show up in a star system*. I think it may have been because the system was not developed to level 2 (modernization?). I'll test it again today.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to build the wonder improvements unlocks with the activation of the corresponding deed, in this case Empire development stage 2.

If you have this deed unlocked it should show up in the star system improvement list. You might have to scroll down to see it if you have many other improvements unlocked and it might be grayed out and unselectable if you are mssing the required strategic ressources (10 titanium and 10 hyperium).

If it does not show up, check if you have already queued the improvement in another system, you can only queue it once in your empire.

Comment: That's the thing. The deed was unlocked but it wasn't in the improvement list or queued. If it were a resource issue, then it would still be listed but greyed out and unclickable. 
Weirdly enough about an hour after I posted the question, it did show up in a star system. I think it may have been b/c the system wasn't developed to level 2 (modernization?). I'll test it again today.

Comment: That is indeed strange, i just tried it out on a fresh game too. Just for reference, what race are you using and do you have any other systems? As far as i know modernization is not important for building wonders.

Comment: Since they are wonders, you should also check to see if anyone else has built them @KareemElashmawy. You can do that in the technology screen, which should indicate if someone beat you to it. I have lost the ability to build some wonders before even unlocking them, mostly because I simply focused in other areas of the tech tree.